# What techniques can web server use against user and how to prevent it?

Tags: web-browser

As we surf the web and visit various sites there is a chance to visit malicious web site.

I wish to know what methods can malicious web server use against it's visitor, and what can we do about it, what defensive measures can one make upfront?

I assume this can be split into privacy theft and compromise of a system.
I'm more interested in how can malicious web server compromise my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A malicious remote site can make you download and execute malware. This can be done without user interaction by using a bug in the browser - this is called a drive-by download. Today's browsers are fairly robust against this, but not totally secure.

More common today are code execution with user interaction by tricking the user into downloading a file and then explicitly executing it. These are social attacks, like claiming to have a (fake) updates or some (fake) essential plugin or throwing some error messages and then offering help with some (fake) antivirus or similar. Best protection against this, apart from not falling for these tricks, is to isolate the browser by running it on a separate system so that your main system gets not affected. Typical is a browser in a virtual machine or a remote browser.

Another social attack is credential phishing, where the malicious site makes up some story which involves that you need to enter your credentials (user, password ...). These captured information then will be misused to access other systems with your identity or even to completely take over these identities from you. Best protection against this, apart from not falling for these tricks, is to use 2FA with methods which are bound to the domain - like WebAuthn. The commonly used TOTP or SMS tokens instead are not bound to the domain and can be phished too.

A malicious site can also use vulnerabilities in other sites to use for misusing your logged in identity  - see XSS and CSRF attacks. If this vulnerability site is a relevant infrastructure component like a router this might also allow compromising the rest of your network. Using a different browser or browser profile for important sites with authentication (like router access, online banking, web based mail etc) helps here.

These are the major attacks, there might be others too. In general it helps to isolate your important web use from the rest, with different browser profiles, different browsers or even different systems where the browsers run on.